# automatic updating of timestamps in tables with no model

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web, laravel

Doesn't `laravel` automatically update the `timestamps` of tables which have no `model`, like a `'pivot'` table? I have tried doing it but it doesn't update `timestamps`.

And if it doesn't update it, is there a way we can do it using `laravel`? Or the only way is to update them manually by updating the columns `'created_at'` or `'updated_at'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel only updates those fields when you're using a modal. If you want to update them manually then you can do so.

```
DB::table('table')->where('id', '=', '1')->update(array(
    'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the withTimestamp() on the relationship involving the pivot.

```
//class User

    public function items() 
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('Items')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Comment: there is not necessarily a pivot